# Using Appium GeckoDriver for Firefox on Windows/Linux

Tags: c#, appium, geckodriver

I'm looking for examples in C# on how to launch Firefox and set capabilities in C# on Windows/Linux desktop.

The Appium [dotnet-client](https://github.com/appium/dotnet-client/wiki/Get-Started!) has next to nothing.
The [Appium GeckoDriver](https://github.com/appium/appium-geckodriver) examples are in Python using methods like `driver.get("url")` and `driver.Remote("url", options)` that isn't included in the Appium.WebDriver NuGet.

And I can't read how to use `AppiumOptions().AddAdditionalCapability("x", "y");` from the python code examples.

I'm looking for basics like how to start the browser without having to supply an URL, be able to reset the browser window (cache etc.) without shutting down Firefox between runs, and general examples on good practice for starting the driver in C#.